# How should I average groups of rows in a matrix to produce a new, smaller matrix?

Tags: matlab

I have a very large matrix (216 rows, 31286 cols) of doubles. For reasons specific to the data, I want to average every 9 rows to produce one new row. So, the new matrix will have 216/9=24 rows.

I am a Matlab beginner so I was wondering if this solution I came up with can be improved upon. Basically, it loops over every group, sums up the rows, and then divides the new row by 9. Here's a simplified version of what I wrote:

```
matrix_avg = []
for group = 1:216/9
    new_row = zeros(1, 31286);
    idx_low = (group - 1) * 9 + 1;
    idx_high = idx_low + 9 - 1;
    % Add the 9 rows to new_row
    for j = idx_low:idx_high
        new_row = new_row + M(j,:);
    end
    % Compute the mean
    new_row = new_row ./ 9
    matrix_avg = [matrix_avg; new_row];
end
```

Comment: You could try [`decimate`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/toolbox/signal/ref/decimate.html) which uses a Chebyshev filter or [`downsample`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/toolbox/signal/ref/downsample.html) which takes every n'th row, but I'm not sure of an in-built version that does an average.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `reshape` your big matrix from 216 x 31286 to  9 x (216/9 * 31286).

Then you can use `mean`, which operates on each column. Since your matrix only has 9 rows per column, this takes the 9-row average.

Then you can just `reshape` your matrix back.

```
% generate big matrix
M = rand([216 31286]);
n = 9   % want 9-row average.

% reshape
tmp = reshape(M, [n prod(size(M))/n]);
% mean column-wise (and only 9 rows per col)
tmp = mean(tmp);
% reshape back
matrix_avg = reshape(tmp, [ size(M,1)/n size(M,2) ]);
```

In a one-liner (but why would you?):

```
matrix_avg = reshape(mean(reshape(M,[n prod(size(M))/n])), [size(M,1)/n size(M,2)]);
```

Note - this will have problems if the number of rows in `M` isn't exactly divisible by 9, but so will your original code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would this be faster than the code I proposed? I suppose the mean function is optimized for this kind of task?

Comment: It would be quite a bit faster - in general if you can use a matlab built-in function (like `mean`), it'll be much faster than code written in matlab (for loops), because the matlab built-in code usually calls some C code that does all the work (which is as fast as you can get).

Comment: I tried it also with blockproc, but the method you propose here is far more fast (10-2500 times faster depends on block size).

Comment: I gave it a try with the real data, and this is about 4 times faster! Unfortunately, it doesn't really matter since both of our solutions take less than one second anyway. (finally got around to benchmarking it) Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I measured the 4 solutions and here are the results:

```
reshape: Elapsed time is 0.017242 seconds.
blockproc [9 31286]: Elapsed time is 0.242044 seconds.
blockproc [9 1]: Elapsed time is 44.477094 seconds.
accumarray: Elapsed time is 103.274071 seconds.
```

This is the code I used:

```
M = rand(216,31286);

fprintf('reshape: ');
tic;
n = 9;
matrix_avg1 = reshape(mean(reshape(M,[n prod(size(M))/n])), [size(M,1)/n size(M,2)]);
toc

fprintf('blockproc [9 31286]: ');
tic;
fun = @(block_struct) mean(block_struct.data);
matrix_avg2 = blockproc(M,[9 31286],fun);
toc

fprintf('blockproc [9 1]: ');
tic;
fun = @(block_struct) mean(block_struct.data);
matrix_avg3 = blockproc(M,[9 1],fun);
toc

fprintf('accumarray: ');
tic;
[nR,nC] = size(M);
n2average = 9;
[xx,yy] = ndgrid(1:nR,1:nC);
x = ceil(xx/n2average); %# makes xx 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 etc
matrix_avg4 = accumarray([xx(:),yy(:)],M(:),[],@mean);
toc
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative based on `accumarray`. You create an array with row and column indices into `matrix_avg` that tells you which element in `matrix_avg` a given element in `M` contributes to, then you use `accumarray` to average the elements that contribute to the same element in `matrix_avg`. This solution works even if the number of rows in `M` is not divisible by 9.

```
M = rand(216,31286);
[nR,nC] = size(M);
n2average = 9;

[xx,yy] = ndgrid(1:nR,1:nC);
x = ceil(xx/n2average); %# makes xx 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 etc

matrix_avg = accumarray([xx(:),yy(:)],M(:),[],@mean);
```